# How to correctly write this C# program?

Tags: c#, arrays

This program may seem very easy for C# programmers but, I'm new to C# programming. I have written half of the program so far but, I'm not sure how to finish the rest of the steps. Here is the program I've written and the instructions. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Arrays
{
 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
      int[] array;
      Random randomNumbers = new Random();

      for( int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
      {

         NumInput[randomValue];
         int randomValue = randomNumbers.Next(0, 500);  

      } 


     for( int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
     {

        Console.WriteLine("The array value is: ", NumInput[i]); 

     } 


  }

  }


}
```

The instructions:

Develop a C# console application that implements an int array. Use 2 'for' loops, the first to fill the array using the Random class to generate random integers using the next method of the Random class and a second for loop to iterate through the filled array and print the values entered into the array by the random number generator. Use the array’s length variable to stay within the array bounds for both loops.

Possible output might look like this:

The array value is 488

The array value is 402

The array value is 237

The array value is 48

The array value is 390

The array value is 186

The array value is 425

The array value is 342

The array value is 477

The array value is 319

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You can start by defining an `int` array called `array`...

Comment: Okay and the correct way to write that would be int[] array; right?

Comment: and the instruction says: make TWO (that is 2) for loops. Currently you have one. Be aware that one of the most underdevelopped skills of softwaredevelopers is reading....

Comment: Man what are you guys all critics has everyone forgotten where they stated out?

Comment: @user2888973 "Here is the program I've written" is more likely "here is the code I've been given to complete for my homework"

Comment: I just started programming a week ago lol. Compared to a C# programmer who beens programming longer than a week I think its okay for me to ask a question like this.

Comment: Comon soon, David Arno, Cheesebaron, Rohit Vats, marc_s... have you guys forgotten when you had to write your first code? How many days did that take?

Answer (score 3):

The instructions:

Develop a C# console application that implements an **int array**. **Use 2 'for' loops**, the **first to fill** the array using the Random class to generate random integers using the next method of the Random class and **a second for loop to iterate through the filled array and print the values** entered into the array by the random number generator. Use the array’s length variable to stay within the array bounds for both loops.

I will not solve your homework but I can teach you how to solve this

in essence your program should look like

- Create the int array
- Use a for loop to fill the array with random numbers
- Use a for loop to output the numbers

First go take a look in your book how to create the int array and how to initialize it. While you are at it read also how to set the different values in that array.
When you have done leave me comment and edit your code in your post

Answer (score 2):

Define an array. Use 2 'for' loops, the first to fill the array using the Random class to generate random integers using the next method of the Random class and a second for loop to iterate through the filled array and print the values entered into the array by the random number generator. Use the array’s length variable to stay within the array bounds for both loops.

Sorry for being flippant, but my point is that the instructions can't expressed in a clearer way than they already are. You could tell us which instruction you don't understand however.

Comment: How would I generate random numbers into the array

Comment: Step 1 is to define an array because that is missing from your code. Google "define an array in c#" gives loads of results, and this is the top link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx. MSDN is the best place for c# development resources and documentation.

Comment: Okay you can see now that I have edited the code and defined an array. What corrections should I make to the code for it to work properly though? I know it looks sloppy but, I just began programming less than 10 hours ago.

Comment: you still need to initialize the array... right now it can not contain any values.